# Setup authenticate_user for an entire namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, namespaces

I have an admin namespace setup as so:

```
namespace :admin do
  ...
end
```

I was just wondering if there was a way to use the devise before_filter, `authenticate_user` for all controllers inside the admin namespace instead of invoking this method in every individual controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the callback at the top level in your "base" admin controller like so:

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_admin_user!
end
```

This will affect any controller that inherits from the `AdminController`

In this example you have a generic admin controller where you want to put methods that are common to admin controllers:

```
class Admin::GenericAdminController < Admin::AdminController
  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: One thing to note, Devise is smart enough to determine the `before_action` based on what you name it in your routes. In this case it was, `authenticate_admin`. Thanks for your help.